# How to signout programmatically from Liferay custom portlet

Tags: liferay, logout, liferay-6

I am creating a custom portlet.

And I need to log-out the User from the portal after he performs some operation in my custom portlet. I am extending liferay's `MVCPortlet`.

In one of `MyPortlet`'s action methods I need to write the code to logout the user and then redirect it to the home page.

**Update:**
I tried the following which I think logs out the user but does not redirect to the home page after logging out:

```
actionResponse.sendRedirect(PortalUtil.getPortalURL(actionRequest) + "/c/portal/logout");
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

Well this may be a very late reply, but it may help somebody

Firstly, you have to validate the session and the re-direct to the logout URL. Otherwise, the session remains and the user is moved to the landing page, even though we redirect to the logout url. So, this is what one should do

```
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest);
request.getSession().invalidate();
actionResponse.sendRedirect(themeDisplay.getURLSignOut());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I also did not find a way to send a specific redirect by using liferay's default logout (/c/portal/logout). So I logged out the user programmatically with the util class `AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil` and 
afterwards sending a specific redirect location within the response object, e.g. `response.sendRedirect(yourLocation)`

Note:
With Liferay 7.2 I used `AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil.signOutSimultaneousLogins(userId)` instead of `AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil.logout(userId)` which did not work for me. 
hth

Comment: Please try to be more clear while answering a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to c/portal/logout
more precisely :

> actionResponse.sendRedirect("/c/portal/logout/");

Comment: I tried a variation of this (see my updated question) but it does not redirect to the home page after calling the logout action.

Comment: Then you have to set the default logout page for you portal. To do this , go to Control-->PanelPortal-->Portal Settings, edit and you'll see the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here after facing this problem (LR7):

```
    try {
        AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil.logout(request, response);

        request.setAttribute(WebKeys.LOGOUT, true);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is

perform operation: at the end of operation use this:

```
HttpSession session = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request).getSession();
session.invalidate();


try {
    System.out.println(" redirecting to the required page");
                    response.sendRedirect(themeDisplay.getPortalURL() + "/page-on-which-to-be-redirected");

    } catch (IOException e1) {

          e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```